# Typescript: Cannot export a module that is a generic interface and contains other generic interfaces

Tags: class, generics, module, export, typescript

I'm trying to write a CommonJS declaration file for Bluebird, a promise library that directly exports a generic Promise class. However, the library also exports several other generic classes as static members (PromiseInspection), and it seems like its impossible to model this with typescript.

Edit: Usage example, to illustrate how the module's exported class works:

```
import Promise = require('bluebird');
var promise:Promise<number> = Promise.cast(5);
var x:Promise.PromiseInspection<number> = promise.inspect();
```

I tried several strategies - simplified examples follow:

#### 1. The obvious way

```
declare module "bluebird" {
    class PromiseInspection<T> {
        // ...
    }
    class Promise<T> {
        PromiseInspection: typeof PromiseInspection; // error
        constructor<T>();
        inspect():PromiseInspection<T>; // error
        static cast<U>(value:U):Promise<U>; 
        // ...
    }
    export = Promise;
}
```

Fails with the error unable to use private type `PromiseInspection` as a public property

#### 2. Using a static interface

```
declare module "bluebird2" {
    interface PromiseInspection<T> {
        // ...  
    }
    interface Promise<T> {
        constructor<T>();
        inspect():PromiseInspection<T>;
    }
    interface PromiseStatic {
        new<T>();
        PromiseInspection:typeof PromiseInspection;
        cast<U>(value:U):Promise<U>; // error
    }
    export = PromiseStatic;
}
```

Also fails similarly, but this time the private type is Promise

#### 3. Trying to directly export a constructor function from the module

```
declare module "bluebird3" {
    export interface PromiseInspection<T> {
        // ...
    }
    export interface Promise<T> {
        constructor<T>();
        inspect():PromiseInspection<T>;
    }

    export new<T>(); // syntax error
    export function cast<U>(value:U):Promise<U>; 
}
```

This almost works, except of course its impossible to a constructor function that way.

#### 4. The namespace polluting way (Works, with downsides)

```
interface PromiseInspection<T> {
    // ...
}
interface Promise<T> {
    constructor<T>();
    inspect():PromiseInspection<T>;
}

declare module "bluebird4" {    
    interface PromiseStatic {
        new<T>():Promise<T>;
        PromiseInspection: typeof PromiseInspection;
        cast<U>(value:U):Promise<U>;
    }
    export = PromiseStatic;
}
```

Works, but it pollutes the global namespace with both Promise and PromiseInspection. This *might* be okay but I'd rather avoid it as in CommonJS its usually considered unacceptable.

#### 5. With declaration merging (gets me 90% of the way...)

```
declare module "bluebird5" {
    module Promise {
        export interface PromiseInspection<T> {
            value(): T;
            // ...
        }
        export
        function cast<U>(value: U): Promise<U> ;
    }

    class Promise<T> {
        new <T> (): Promise <T> ;
        inspect(): Promise.PromiseInspection <T> ;
    }

    export = Promise;
}
```

Almost there - except that now I'm not allowed to replace `class Promise<T>` with `interface Promise<T>`, making `Promise<T>` unextendable. If I try to do it, the following code:

```
import Promise = require('bluebird');
var x = new Promise<number>();
x.inspect().value().toExponential();
```

fails with the error "Invalid 'new' expression"

[Link to the actual, work-in-progress bluebird.d.ts](https://gist.github.com/spion/8327702) - this one currently pollutes the global namespace (uses solution 4)

Is there a better way to do this, or did I hit a language limitation?

Answer (score 5):

Anders Hejlsberg posted an answer on CodePlex, so I'm going to add it here. The declaration merging solution was close - but I also needed a "var" declaration to declare the static interface as it is the only one that can accept a constructor function.

```
declare module "bluebird" {
    module Promise {
        export interface PromiseInspection<T> {
            value(): T;
        }
    }
    interface Promise<T> {
        inspect(): Promise.PromiseInspection <T> ;
    }

    var Promise: {
        new<U>(): Promise<U>;
        cast<U>(value: U): Promise<U> ;
    }
    export = Promise;
}
```

So basically:

- interface members in the module declaration (as long as they declare just types i.e. non-physical)
- instance members in the main interface
- static function members, the constructor and other "physical" members in the var declaration.

Also, his comment:

> Writing it this way you have a separate declaration for each of the three meanings of the identifier Promise: As a namespace (a module containing only types), as a type (that happens to be generic), and as a value.

Comment: Hi Gorgi, what's the status of the BB definition file? I don't see a pull request on DefinitelyTyped and I'd like to use this.

Comment: @SeanClarkHess looks like someone beat me to it. See https://github.com/spion/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/bluebird/bluebird.d.ts

Comment: My version works better in node and can be found here - https://github.com/spion/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/bluebird

Comment: Awesome. Have you already made a pull request for it? If not you should! Thank you!

Comment: @SeanClarkHess - I've been running into issues with ts 0.9.5 and node, where just using something that returns promises requires the promise library to be imported. I decided to give up on typescript for now until Microsoft decide to get their act together and fix the issues they introduced in the latest version.

Comment: bummer. I have things working nicely with Q right now. Just waiting to switch to bluebird until the definitions are better.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I noticed you were missing a few `export` statements.  The code below compiles - would it suit?

```
declare module bluebird {
    export class PromiseInspection<T> {
        // ...
    }
    export class Promise<T> {
        constructor<T>();
        inspect():PromiseInspection<T>;
        static all<T>(promises:Promise<T>[]):Promise<T[]>;
    }
}

declare module "bluebird" {
    export = bluebird;
}
```

Though I generally favour using interfaces when defining typings as in #2:

```
declare module bluebird {
    export interface PromiseInspection<T> {
        // ...
    }
    export interface Promise<T> {
        constructor<T>();
        inspect():PromiseInspection<T>;
    }
    export interface PromiseStatic {
        new<T>();
        all<T>(promises:Promise<T>[]):Promise<T[]>;
    }
}

declare module "bluebird" {
    export = bluebird;
}
```

Failing that have you tried using another promises library as the basis for your typings?  You could do worse than look at https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/q/Q.d.ts

Roughly speaking they look a little like this:

```
declare function Q<T>(promise: Q.IPromise<T>): Q.Promise<T>;
declare function Q<T>(promise: JQueryPromise<T>): Q.Promise<T>;
declare function Q<T>(value: T): Q.Promise<T>;

declare module Q {
    //… functions etc in here
}

declare module "q" {
    export = Q;
}
```

Comment: Yes I actually did use Q as a base, however Q exports its promise class as Q.Promise, while Bluebird exports the class constructor itself... edit: I added a link to the actual bluebird.d.ts

Comment: Regarding the missing export statements - Bluebird is not a module containing a "Promise" class. The module *is* the Promise class, but also with a static meber PromiseInspection that is itself a generic class. I will add a usage example to illustrate

Comment: Added usage example, illustrating why I use `export = Interface` or `export = Class`